# how to CENTER a child view in RelativeLayout using addRule

Tags: android

I have `RelativeLayout` R1 which contains two `ImageView` V1,V2
I want to align V2 so it is centered in V1, and without using any other views, Is it possible?

```
p.s it is possible to use ALIGN_RIGHT , ALIGN_TOP , but there is not ALIGN_CENTER
```

Comment: Can you give some picture examples or maybe your code to demonstrate what you want?

Comment: Do you mean one view under another view centered to the center of the view above it? A little more detail would help, but if that's what you're doing, you could just put a LinearLayout around the two with orientation="vertical" and layout_width="wrap_content" then center everything inside of it.

Comment: i know it's possible using linear layout and gravity, i am trying to avoid using a GroupView inside another GroupView